# Pandas data frame column containing list of dicts

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I have the following pandas data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'info':[1.4,3.6,6.5], 'new':[[{'score':0.998, 'letters':'C', 'temp':1}, {'score':1.343, 'letters':'B', 'temp':0}, {'score':2.323, 'letters':'F', 'temp':1}], [{'score':2.532, 'letters':'D', 'temp':1}, {'score':2.123, 'letters':'G', 'temp':1}, {'score':4.332, 'letters':'S', 'temp':0}], [{'score':2.223, 'letters':'C', 'temp':0}, {'score':1.144, 'letters':'J', 'temp':1}, {'score':7.443, 'letters':'G', 'temp':9}]]})
```

df:

```
    info    new
0   1.4 [{'score': 0.998, 'letters': 'C', 'temp': 1}, ...
1   3.6 [{'score': 2.532, 'letters': 'D', 'temp': 1}, ...
2   6.5 [{'score': 2.223, 'letters': 'C', 'temp': 0}, ...
```

I'm trying to get the score values and letters values from each dictionary and get the following output:

```
  info    score1    score2    score3   letters1   letters2   letters3
0 1.4     0.998     1.343     2.323    C          B          F
1 3.6     2.532     2.123     4.332    D          G          S
2 6.5     2.223     1.144     7.443    C          J          G
```

I have tried this:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
records = [x[0] for x in df['new']]

res = pd.concat([df.drop('new', axis=1), json_normalize(records)], axis=1)
```

I have also tried:

```
df = df['new'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series({i['score']: i['letters'] for i in x if isinstance(x, list)}))
```

Any help would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use list with dict comprehension for new columns names with `enumerate`:

```
d = [{f'{k}{i}': v for i,y in enumerate(x, 1) for k,v in y.items()} for x in df['new']]

df = pd.DataFrame(d, index=df.index).sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
  letters1 letters2 letters3  score1  score2  score3  temp1  temp2  temp3
0        C        B        F   0.998   1.343   2.323      1      0      1
1        D        G        S   2.532   2.123   4.332      1      1      0
2        C        J        G   2.223   1.144   7.443      0      1      9
```

---

```
d = [{f'{k}{i}': v for i,y in enumerate(x, 1) for k,v in y.items() if k in ['score','letters']} for x in df.pop('new')]

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(d, index=df.index).sort_index(axis=1))
print (df)
   info letters1 letters2 letters3  score1  score2  score3
0   1.4        C        B        F   0.998   1.343   2.323
1   3.6        D        G        S   2.532   2.123   4.332
2   6.5        C        J        G   2.223   1.144   7.443
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
df = df.explode('new')
#pd.json_normalize(df['new'])
df2 = pd.concat([df['info'].reset_index(drop = True), pd.json_normalize(df['new'])], axis = 1)
```

explode will take take it out of the list and then normalise the dictionary thereafter

Answer (score 0):

- `explode()` and expand columns
- reshape exploded and expanded dataframe and `join()` back to original

```
df2 = (
    df.explode("new")["new"]
    .apply(pd.Series)
    .pipe(lambda d: d.assign(obs=d.groupby(level=0).cumcount() + 1))
    .set_index("obs", append=True)
    .unstack("obs")
)

df2.columns = ["".join(map(str, c)) for c in df2.columns.to_flat_index()]
df.loc[:, ["info"]].join(df2)
```

|  | info | score1 | score2 | score3 | letters1 | letters2 | letters3 | temp1 | temp2 | temp3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.4 | 0.998 | 1.343 | 2.323 | C | B | F | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 3.6 | 2.532 | 2.123 | 4.332 | D | G | S | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 6.5 | 2.223 | 1.144 | 7.443 | C | J | G | 0 | 1 | 9 |